# undefined method `connection'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I started creating an Admin panel for a project, so I decided to use Active Admin. I generated the config, and the resources as written in the documentation.

My problem is that I can't access any of my resources, I always get the following screen:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea of how to solve this. I tried to comment each line written in the extracted source, but I still have that error.

I'm running Rails 4.2.1 with Ruby 2.3.0p0

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
    config.site_title = "Let's Dev !"

    config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!

    config.current_user_method = :current_user

    config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path

    config.batch_actions = true

    config.localize_format = :long

end
```

Comment: Please post a text, not an image.

Comment: well obviously you messed up somewhere in the config, so please post it along with the resources

Comment: I updated the post with the configuration

Comment: @SofianeGARGOURI I was checking the Active Admin gem installation for ROR...I did not see any such configuration to be done....Can you provide more details as what are you trying to actually do...

Comment: @SnehaT I'm just trying to initialize my admin panel. Actually, I just added my resources to ActiveAdmin with the following commands:

- rails generate active_admin:resource User
- rails generate active_admin:resource Note